# SSIS flat file with string larger than 50

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

SSIS by default makes the datatype to be String with length 50, what if the string in a certain column is larger than 50 and also I can't use suggest types (it sucks!).

Is there a way to fix this, rather than manually increasing the sizes ie. manually editing the column lengths/datatypes in the flat file manager's advanced tab, ideally changing datatypes based on the destination (sql server) mapping columns' datatypes?

Answer (score 3):

You can set datatypes in the flat file connection manager.  In the advanced section.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that - I know it can be set in flat file or use suggested types but i want it to happen in an automated way (it should either automatically pick up based on the destination(sql server) table mappings  - is there a way to do that)?

Comment: SSIS is more concerned with not losing any source data, so it sizes the columns based on those values.  You also can't really trust the suggest sizing tool, unless you create some dummy data that uses the entire length of the column, but you'll probably spend as much time doing that as going through the flat file properties.  Unfortunately the best way to do this is to enter them manually off a spec.  I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/), but haven't used it myself.

I haven't found a way to change default length, or to stop it from resetting when changing the connection manager.  I was pleased that you can select all columns at once in the advanced editor and change them simultaneously, that's something...

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could do this was write C# code that modifies the ssis package xml file and increases  the string length values by looking at the lengths of the destination table (using information_schema query)